# Corollary from Maximum Modulus Principle and Schwarz's Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Need to prove this implication derived from the maximum principle, but have no clue how.

$$\forall k=0,...,N. \ f^{(k)}(0)=0 \implies\exists M=const . \ \forall z.|z|\lt1:|f(z)|\le M|z|^{N+1}$$

Comment: Do you mean $f^{(k)} (0) = 0$? And where does the constant $M$ come from?

Comment: @HansEngler M is just some constant

Comment: I think you want $|f(z)| \le M$ for $|z| = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is stated, you don't need the maximum modulis principle.

The assumption that $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $k = 0, \dots, N$ implies that $f(z)$ has a zero of order $N+1$ at the origin. Therefor, the function
$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^{N+1}}$$ 
is analytic in the closed unit disc (assuming that $f$ is analytic in the closed unit disc that is). By compactness of the closed unit disc, there is a constant $M$ such that $|g(z)| \leq M$ in $|z|\leq 1$. That is,
$|f(z)| \leq M |z|^{N+1}$
in $|z|\leq 1$.

If you use the maximum modulis principle, then you can deduce that
$|f(z)| < M |z|^{N+1}$ in $|z|< 1$.

Notice that the assumption that $f$ is analytic in the closed unit disc is essential. The function $f(z) = \frac{z^{N+1}}{1-z}$ fulfilles your assumption, but tends to $\infty$ as $z\rightarrow 1^-$.

Comment: The conclusion is still $|f(z)| \le M |z|^{N+1}$ when MMP is used; strict inequality would fail at $z=0$.